# S3PrefixSensor in MWAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I am using the S3PrefixSensor in MWAA v2.2.2, where I am waiting for some file to appear in S3 bucket. Here is my relevant code

```
s3_success_flag_sensor = S3PrefixSensor(
    task_id='s3_success_flag',
    bucket_name=MY_BUCKET,
    prefix=MY_PREFIX,
    retries=3,
    dag=dag,
)
```

I would expect the DAG to see that the file is there, on S3 and continue to next operator, however this is what I see in logs (replaced real path and real s3 bucket name):

```
[2022-03-17, 09:30:03 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:31:04 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:32:06 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:33:07 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:34:08 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:35:09 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:36:10 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:37:12 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:38:13 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:39:14 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:40:15 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:41:16 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:42:17 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:43:18 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:44:19 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:45:21 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:46:22 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:47:23 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:48:24 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
[2022-03-17, 09:49:25 UTC] {{s3_prefix.py:77}} INFO - Poking for prefix : ['SOME_EXISTING_PATH_ON_S3'] in bucket s3://SOME_EXISTING_S3_BUCKET
```

The file is already there, however the sensor continues to poke.

Comment: If it continue to poke then the file is not there. Are you sure the region is configured correctly?

Comment: Yep. I used S3KeySensor for the same file and it works for me. Will double check.

Comment: The issue is most likely with the connection. Since you didn't specify one it falls back to aws_default. Check this connection details.

Comment: once again, it works with S3KeySensor. We have aws role defined in aws_default. The region defined correctly.

Comment: S3PrefixSensor has default `/` for `delimiter` parameter.

Comment: yep, i saw that, tried even to replace it with comma and replace `/` within the path i use - nothing helped. I have developed my own operator that does the job, but i'd like to use  the original one.

Comment: Check this:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fc44836504129664edb81c510e6deb41a7e1126d/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3.py#L212
I think your issue is because you didn't fully understand how delimiter works with prefix. If there is a bug it's not with the Sensor it's with the hook functions.

Answer (score 1):

`S3PrefixSensor` does not wait for a given prefix in S3 to exist but it waits for a given folder in S3 to exist (given the delimiter is `/`)

Since this is very confusing Airflow deprecated `S3PrefixSensor` in favor of `S3keySensor` (see [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22737))

For [`apache-airflow-providers-amazon>3.3.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-amazon):

Noting: By the time of writing this answer there is no version newer than 3.3.0 but it will be released in the next few weeks.

The usage is:

```
s3_sensor_key = S3KeySensor(
    task_id="s3_sensor_key",
    bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
    bucket_key="my_k*",
    wildcard_match=True,
)
```

This will search for prefix of `my_k`. It uses Unix wildcard pattern.

For [`apache-airflow-providers-amazon<=3.3.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-amazon):

Create a custom sensor by copy the [S3KeySensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/dffb0d27f25b9a1f2497535cb87de3b889aae9d0/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/sensors/s3.py#L42-L152) source code from Airflow main branch. Then import the class and use the example usage as shown above.
This will work assuming you are using `Apache-Airflow>=2.1.0` if not then you will need to make further adjustments to the Sensor to make it compatible with older Airflow versions.